# Thermodynamics Availablity why use surrounding pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics

The formula for availability in thermodynamics is given by: 
$$A=U+p_sV-T_sS$$
Where $p_s$ and $T_s$ are related to the surroundings. I understand why we use the temperature $T_s$ instead of the system temperature but not why we use $p_s$ instead of the system pressure. This is because the $p_sV$ term comes from the work done on the surroundings and therefore shouldn't take its usual form of $pV$.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, in the thermodynamics we have learnt, we only consider the case that the system is at its equilibrium or at least close to equilibrium. So the pressure of the system  must be similiar to the pressure of the outside surroundings, the environment, or the system will not be equilibrium. That is why we talk about a quasi-static process in thermodynamics.

And in non-equilibrium themodynamics, you can't even define a pressure for the system as a whole. So there is no need to talk about A, P or U

Answer (score 0):

I do not mean to be glib about but if you were to use the system (internal) pressure in the definition, such as $A'= U+pV-T_s S$ it would not be availability, it would be something else, a variation on enthalpy. There is nothing wrong with that, it is just something else. But if you use the definition as $A=U+p_s V - T_s S$ this quantity describes, for example, the equilibrium of a system that is coupled to a pressure $p_s$ (work) and a thermal $T_s$ reservoir, and also the maximum amount of *useful* work available from the system for a given change of $A$.